ASP.NET Core Middleware is not awaited after next(context)
I created a middleware to execute a request under a DB transaction if a custom attribute is defined on an endpoint. I have a test which does following:

Calls such an endpoint which modifies data in DB under transaction.
Calls a separate GET-endpoint to ensure that data is persisted as expected.

What sometimes happens is that a second call to a GET-endpoint fails. In the log I clearly see that "Transaction completed" message appears AFTER GET-request is received. I suspect that response is sent back to the client before the CommitAsync is executed. I believe I could just add a delay to my test between 1st and 2nd actions but I want to understand why it happens.
Please help me to understand the problem and possible solutions.
public class DbTransactionAttribute : Attribute { }

public class DbTransactionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public DbTransactionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IDbContext dbContext, ILogger<DbTransactionMiddleware> logger)
    {
        var attribute = context.Features
            .Get<IEndpointFeature>()
            ?.Endpoint
            ?.Metadata
            .GetMetadata<DbTransactionAttribute>();

        if (attribute == null)
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        else
        {
            using (var trx = await dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
            {
                try
                {
                    await _next(context);
                    await trx.CommitAsync();
                    logger.LogInformation("Transaction completed");
                }
                catch
                {
                    await trx.RollbackAsync();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Startup:
            app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlerMiddleware>();

            app.UseApplicationCors();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseApplicationSwagger();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseMiddleware<DbTransactionMiddleware>(); // this is the middleware
            app.UseApplicationEndpoints(); // here we call UseEndpoints
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();

UPD #1:
here is a little bit modified code, which shows how test works. Of course, it makes second request sequentially, only after it gets and validates response for the first request
            var result = await RestCalls.ModifyData(user, someEntity.Id, new() { Parameter = sum },
                x => ReplyValidator.Validate(x, expectedError: expectedError));

            // some additional validation

            await ValidateGetRequest(user, someEntity, expected);


It seems like there is an async method that is not await

@Damien it could be, but there no warnings in my solution, also I checked that there are no async void methods.

Do you make both requests in parallel? Could you publish a snippet of your test code?

@MuhammadJavad updated the question. All requests are made sequentially

your issue seems to be related the asynchronous execution where the HTTP response might start sending before the database transaction commits. your code looks correct but make sure your DbTransactionMiddleware is correctly placed in the pipeline to commit transactions before any response is sent. Check the order and execution flow of your middleware.

@JalpaPanchal the DbTransactionMiddlware is placed right before UseEndpoints...

"What sometimes happens is that a second call to a GET-endpoint fails" how does it fail?

could you try to add logging around the transaction commit and the actual sending of the HTTP response. This can help determine exactly when the response starts being sent relative to the transaction commit.
